# Why I cannot set Django settings DATABASES engine to Postgis?

Tags: django, heroku, postgis, heroku-postgres

I have deploy my Django application to Heroku which involved using GeoDjango features and PostGis database. My settings is something like this.

```py
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_gis',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'service.apps.ServiceConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ARProject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ARProject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {}

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='postgis://...')

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Image upload folder location
UPLOAD_DIR = '/tmp/'

MODELS_DIR = os.path.join('service', 'models')

JSON_PATH = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, 'model.json')

MODELS_PATH = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, 'model.h5')

GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.environ.get('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')

GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.environ.get('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

When I run Django shell

```
>>from django.conf import settings
>>settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']
>>'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' instead of 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
```

I also get the same result even if I set DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] manually in settings.py . I have found some discussion which involved the same problem as mine however their solutions are not working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Django settings are loaded at startup and should not change on runtime https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime.

The reason that this wont work is probably that the DB connections are already loaded by Django so changing the setting wont have any effect.

If you want to use multiple databases, take a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/.

**Updated:**

Looks like `django_heroku.settings(locals())` set the database (https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/master/django_heroku/core.py#L49).

If you change it to `django_heroku.settings(locals(), database=False)` it should not be changed.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry about making that unclear. I don't mean that I want to change on runtime. I've just edited my post , let check it out.

Comment: I don't know what random desperate Google Search finally brought me to this little regarded post, but it solved my issues after failing for days to deploy my GeoDjango app to Heroku. You just made my day @Krukas. Just one hint: The correct argument is `databases` with an s in the end. Can't suggest an edit because it's too few edits. Maybe update it if you can.